# Estimates for k-d tree partition cells and for Voronoi partition cells

Tags: cart, partitioning

Let us have a $k$-d tree in a unit cube in ${\mathbb R}^k$. Let the points of the tree in the cube be i.i.d. with some density bounded away from 0. How can I estimate the volumes of partition rectangles near a fixed point of the cube?

To be more precise. Let $t$ be a fixed point of the cube. Let a $k$-d tree be built by $n$ points. Let $v_1,...,v_m$ be the volumes of the partition rectangles that intersect with the cube with center $t$ and each edge of length $r$. By partition rectangles I mean disjoint rectangles, each of which contains one and only one of the $n$ points.

What estimates may be made for $v_1,...,v_m$?

What estimates may be done for $v_1,...,v_m$ if we consider Voronoi partitioning?